# Is there a better way to match while using `git filter-branch`?

Tags: git, bash, git-filter-branch

I have a problem similar to the one described in question [How do I change the author of a commit in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-do-i-change-the-author-of-a-commit-in-git) and the solution I'm trying is using `git filter-branch` but it doesn't work because it won't match the string literal with spaces i.e. I need `contains`:

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
    if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" = "giovanni azua" ];
    then
            GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="Giovanni Azua";
            GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="giovanni.azua@xxx.com";
            GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Giovanni Azua";
            GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="giovanni.azua@xxx.com";
            git commit-tree "$@";
    else
            git commit-tree "$@";
    fi' HEAD
```

The equal sign will not work if there are spaces in between and I have no idea how to escape it. I have also tried escaping it like `giovanni\ azua` but doesn't work. I also could not find any reference to what this scripting is i.e. how do you do string `contains` or `substring` match? I always get the output `WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged`.

UPDATE: It would also check my box to have a not `if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" ~= "giovanni azua" ];` but the operator `~=` does not work.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want a regular-expression or glob-style match, so that if GIT_AUTHOR_NAME is (say) `pgiovanni azuaq` it should also match?  (Probably not, but this is meant to make you consider exactly what you want to match.)  The test, `if [ ... ]`, simply runs the `[` *program* (see [test](http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?test+1) docs).  Use `expr` or `grep` to run a regular-expression match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scripting used by `git filter-branch` is simply a snippet of `sh`, which means that all capabilities of `sh` and any commands you can call from it (`echo`, `grep`, `sed`, etc.) are at your disposal. To implement wildcard matches, you don't need to invoke external commands, as `sh` provides the somewhat clumsy but useful `case` command. In your case (no pun intended), it could look like this:

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
    case "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" in
      *[Gg]iovanni*[Aa]zua*)
          GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="Giovanni Azua"
          GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="giovanni.azua@xxx.com"
          GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Giovanni Azua"
          GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="giovanni.azua@xxx.com"
          git commit-tree "$@"
          ;;
      *)
          git commit-tree "$@"
          ;;
      esac
' HEAD
```

The above will change all commits whose author name contains `giovanni` or `Giovanni` and `azua` or `Azua` (in that order) anywhere in the author name.